# signal user application from kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, signals

I have been pulling my hairs for real strange issue. The kernel module is unable to send signal to user application (or user app is unable to receive)  without printk, have to do dummy printk after or before sending the signal.

Actually, it works great even with empty printk. But, i am trying to understand whats happening.

Any thoughts?

Here is whats happening:

A - kernel) 
Char device type module gets interrupt.

It extracts the data and send signal to user.

/*  have to do printk here */

Return IRQ handle.

B- user)

Receives the signal.

issues a system call and read the data from char device's buffer . (copy_to_user)

kernel:

```
void irq_handler(){
    int i;
    for(i =0; i < 32; i++) 
        GPIOdata[i] = read_gpio_status(i);

    struct task_struct *p = find_task_by_pid(processinfo.pid);
    if (NULL == p) 
        return;
    send_sig(SIGUSR1, p, 0);
    /* have to add printk here */
    return IRQ_HANDLED
}
```

user:

```
void signal_handler(int sig) {
    char data[32];
    ioctl(fd, READ_Data_from_Char_device, &data);
}
```

Comment: Does your user app ever run again if you don't printk?  Also, how are you signaling the user app?

Comment: User application is running all the time. Without printk the signal_handler is being called but the data (copy from kernel) get corrupted somehow.

Comment: @user2492889 Just a guess - it looks like there is some stack or memory corruption that gets hidden by the `printk` call. But without code its impossible to tell.

Comment: @bbonev You got a valid point and I think that could be the case. Any idea how to dig in?

Comment: @user2492889 Code looks pretty straightforward... I am not sure if `find_task_by_pid` and `send_sig` are safe to be called from interrupt context. A way to overcome this is to call it from softirq context via tasklet, or even user context via work queue. Another way of doing the same job is to register a netlink socket and send the data as broadcast so all interested user processes. They will get both the notification and the data itself.

Comment: returning `IRQ_HANDLED` from a `void` function looks bonkers to me. Try **`irqreturn_t irq_handler()`**.

Comment: @bbonev It was very helpful response. Yeah, thinking to give it a try to netlink sockets. Is it user app should do select() in a loop? Bit confused how user apps can be made asynchronous while using netlink/select() design. With signals app is busy doing other stuff and only reading data from module when there is a signal!

Comment: @ila It is very much like a normal socket (e.g. UDP). You can make it non-blocking and do select/epoll...

Comment: @bbonev i guess we are definitely talking about threading here! to make it non-blocking.

Comment: @ila This depends on the design of the userland application. If it is event driven around sockets, netlink will be just one more socket. If it is not, then one thread to process netlink messages will do the job.

Comment: netlink sock will require huge makeover in existing design. Thinking to give a try to proc read/write again with signal. Maybe copy_to_user is causing the memory corruption.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `signal` not `sigaction` for setting handler, then remember, that `signal` removes handler after getting a signal. And you should mask the signal, so it will not interrupt your process when running inside signal handler. I'ma also not sure about system call `ioctl` inside handler (look at [man7 signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) under section Async-signal-safe functions).

Calls to `printk` might slow down execution of other operations (because they are blocked on I/O or buffering) around these calls, so they can make synchronization slower (thus any mistakes in synchronization may not occur).

Comment: That has been resolved. The issue was with memory corruption as point by @user2492889. And yes, you are right that only Async-signal-safe must be used in signal context. printk is always evil in interrupt handling!